# How to use to different dataset and train it with same model

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have two dataset of two different type of ddos attack how do I merge this dataset in one large set to work with? I am trying to train deep learning model on cic ddos 2019 dataset which contains 7 different CSV files of different ddos methods

I tried to merged them together but it didn't

How do I tarin model based on these 7 different datasets for an ids any solution please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if we knew the language you were using. For something like Python I would do something like:

```python3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

csv_files = [...] # list of file paths for your data
dataset = pd.DataFrame()
dataframes = []
for file in csv_files:
    temp = pd.read_csv(file)
    dataframes.append(temp)
dataset = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)
```